# Is it possible to learn a mapping between unpaired time-series data?

Tags: time-series, function

I have two time series. One is an actual recording of physiological signals, the other is a binary representation of activations (0 or 1) based on a **simulation** of the process underlying the physiological signals. The simulations are not aligned with individual recordings of the physiological signals, nor can I assume that the simulation is entirely "correct" (i.e., the simulation might not capture the true underlying process).

Would it still be possible to learn a reasonable mapping between the two signals that could help with the augmentation of the physiological signals (i.e., generating "synthetic" physiological signals)?

Note that I have a limited number of actual recordings but (obviously) a potentially infinite number of simulations.